# Feminine equivalent term for aruji [主]{あるじ}?

Tags: words

Is there a feminine equivalent to aruji? If a servant was addressing a noblewoman, what term would they use? I am looking for the more archaic term, not one that would used in current ordinary speech. (I understand that 'aruji' is fairly archaic.)

Comment: I don't believe 主｛あるじ｝ is a gendered term

Comment: So a servant could refer to a noblewoman as 'aruji'?

Comment: Is this "noblewoman" the owner of the house the servant is serving at? And what's the setting? Japan, or Europe in the Victorian Era, or some *isekai*?

Comment: I think the poster who referred to the Beast girl is thinking of the same scenario that I am. I'm wondering how someone with a dress the Beast girl, if they thought of her as higher status and wanted to Render unto her the same level of respect that she renders to her master. In terms of setting, it's modern Japan, but with a girl whose thought processes are stuck in the Middle Ages

Answer (score 4):

First, 主【あるじ】 is not particularly gender-specific, but it's not a very common way of addressing one's master, either. It sounds relatively blunt and less sophisticated. If you want to play it safe, avoid *aruji* altogether. (It can be natural in some fictional situations, though. For example, one user of *aruji* I know is a young and proud beast girl who is basically loyal to her master but is not good at keigo and treats him like her friend. Other possible users of *aruji* would be a bandit, a samurai living in the countryside, a dwarf living in a remote cave, etc.)

The common words used by classic housemaid/butler/servant type characters are ご主人様 for a male owner, 奥様 for a married woman, and お嬢様 for an unmarried lady. ご主人様 and お嬢様 are something you would hear at "maid cafés" in Japan.

Comment: 「あるじ」に「様」や「殿」を付ければ話は別でしょうか？たとえば、「悪魔執事と黒い猫」の執事たちは、全員プレイヤーのことを「主様」と呼んでいますが、「not good at keigo」なのは数人だけです。

Comment: @Angelos はい、十分に丁寧になると思います。ただし「主様」は、フィクションで、あどけない感じのキャラが使うイメージがあります。現実の成人が使うことはまずないです。